# =Query Function from another sheet based on a cell Value

Tags: google-sheets

Looking for some help with your good skills.

For example:
I setup three Google Sheets

1) Master Sheet (for Sync Function)
2) Company ABC 1
3) Company ABC 2

We always update MasterSheet for tasks and then we create SubSheets for each client but currently, we are updating each sheet for each client manually, but with your help, I would like to make this process bit automatic.

For example if you enter a new task and related details such as, date, company name, job type, job status in the Master Sheet, it should be reflected on Sub-Sheet which we have shared with the client.

Example: 
Company ABC 1 get its own data and ABC 2 and so on...

after watching a few videos I found that I can do this with =Query function but there is a small change I would like to make it a little bit easier.

So what I wanna do is I will have a locked cell on Sub-Sheet where I will dedicate a cell and in that cell if I put the company's name it should simply reflect data based on company name entered in that specific cell.

How can I do that? kindly help.

here is the Master Sheet link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/187PR2oeFelq8qRsK_qY9Fodvedx8ChkvMZTh2Dtll9w/edit#gid=0

here is the ABC 1 Company Sub-Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UsujYx9-tc_DEp4LLCbOISkC1mC0QLVyg0mN36MPhjE/edit#gid=0

here is the ABC 2 Company Sub-Sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AiTTKiVioNtEGPsYDS0xP_K0NpWvEeXmSQJOSVdfMDk/edit#gid=0

Comment: I read your question and even after looking at your sheets I still fail to understand what the issue is. The formula or the locking of the cell. Please clarify.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply and thank you for looking at the sheet for me. here i made a screenshot maybe it could help? http://prntscr.com/soajs5 

Thanks a lot for your reply and thank you for looking at the sheet for me. here I made a screenshot maybe it could help? http://prntscr.com/soajs5 
1) currently I added company name into the forums above but I want to keep a reference cell for entering the company 
2) I added an Invoice link to a hyperlink in Master Sheet but on subsheet it is returning plain text without the link.

Comment: here is the formula i am using 
=QUERY(importrange("187PR2oeFelq8qRsK_qY9Fodvedx8ChkvMZTh2Dtll9w","MasterDashboard!$A$2:$F"),"SELECT * WHERE Col2 = 'ABC1'",1)

Comment: Please check your Sync 1 sheet

Comment: i am inside ABC1 sheet but seems it not returning the data. can we check it now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula in your synced copied sheets.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("xxxxxx","MasterDashboard!A2:F"), "select * where Col2= '"&B1&"' ")
```

*(where `xxxxxx` is your Master sheet ID and `B1` is your reference cell in the synced sheet)*

Notes (for anyone using the formula)

- When using `IMPORTRANGE` one has to use  `Col1`, `Col2` etc
- To reference a cell, the syntax used is, pairs of single quotes `'`, double quotes `"` , ampersand `&`
  As an example:  `'"&TheCellHere&"'`

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`IMPORTRANGE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well. **Also** check the answer in your *"[ABC 1 Company Sub-Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UsujYx9-tc_DEp4LLCbOISkC1mC0QLVyg0mN36MPhjE/edit#gid=1064956477&range=A3)"*

Comment: thanks alot for the help. this is exactly what i wanted. much much appreciated. :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. Glad I could help :)

Comment: what should be the formula if Col2 = company1 or company2